# Getting a white line between the rows in flutter

Tags: flutter

Nowadays i have two `Rows` with a blue `Container`, but between this `Containers` i'm facing a white line (i don't know if the flutter put `padding` or `margin` between the rows).

I try this way:

```
return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue[800],
        elevation: 0.0,
        iconTheme: IconThemeData(
          color: Colors.white, //change your color here
        ),
      ),
      body: Column(children: <Widget>[
        Row(children: [
          Container(
            color: Colors.lightBlue[800],
            height: 170,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      new Container(
                          width: 120.0,
                          height: 120.0,
                          decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                              shape: BoxShape.circle,
                              image: new DecorationImage(
                                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                                  image: new NetworkImage(
                                      "https://i.imgur.com/BoN9kdC.png")))),
                      Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 5, 0, 0),
                          child: Text("RENATO",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  fontSize: 25,
                                  color: Colors.white)))
                    ],
                  ),
                ]),
          ),
        ]),
        Row(children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            color: Colors.lightBlue[800],
            height: 100,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width
          )
        ],)
      ]),
      drawer: Drawer(
        child: SafeArea(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(18.0),
            child: ListView(
              children: <Widget>[
                ListTile(
                  title: Text('Item1'),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

This is the result:
[image]

How i can fix this?

Comment: Did you test it in a real device?

Comment: yes, but affourtunatly now i make a flutter run and now it's working as expected.

Comment: why unfortunatly ? :)

Comment: sorry, i'm learning english, i meant 
occasionally

Comment: No worries , hope that it works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Try remove the border from Container, or set the color of the border to